# cloud function with fetch could not deploy correctly

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

Im currently working on a firebase cloud function which needs to work with my firestore. The structure of my firebase is the following:

`chatrooms/{chatID}/{chatID}/anymessage`

Both chatIDs are same, they resemble an individual chatroom and each chatroom has anymessages inside. Also, each chatroom has a "hello" document in which I have crucial data I need to use inside my cloud function because I need to extract a key from there so I can send a push notification.

This is my cloud function Im trying to deploy currently:

```
exports.createpushnotification = functions.firestore.document('chatrooms/{chatID}/{chatID}/hello').onUpdate((change, context) => {
     const keyofuser1 = change.after.data().partner1pushkey; //key to use for push notification

     fetch("https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send", {
         method:"POST",
         headers:{
             "Accept": "application/json",
             "Content-Type": "application/json"
         },
         body:JSON.stringify({"to":keyofuser1, "body":"New Message!"})
     })
     

 })
```

Basically I want a cloud function which goes into each chatroom directory, fetches the "hello" file from there and waits for it to update and when it does, execute the fetch operation. Unluckily I get an error and even with --debug I can not see any error log that could help me:

> Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
> createpushnotification(us-central1)
>
> To try redeploying those functions, run:
> firebase deploy --only "functions:createpushnotification"
>
> To continue deploying other features (such as database), run:
> firebase deploy --except functions [2021-08-23T07:33:26.669Z]      Error during update for
> projects/*********/locations/us-central1/functions/createpushnotification:
>
> Error: Functions did not deploy properly.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You are not returning the promise. Try adding `return` before `fetch(...)`. Also can you share a screenshot of your Firestore doc? `chatrooms/{chatID}/{chatID}/anymessage` why do you have `chatID` twice?

Comment: "I want a cloud function which **goes into each chatroom directory**, fetches the "hello" file from there" => Your current Cloud Function will not do that. It will be triggered only when **one** hello document will be modified. Can you confirm you want your Cloud Function to read each chatroom collection when it executes?

Comment: @Renaud Tarnec Yes. I want it to go into multiple locations and listen to the "hello" files, as you say.

Comment: @Dharmaraj I have ChatID twice because I needed to structure the Firestore in a way that at the end I have a document. Would I only use "one" ChatID I would have a collection at the endpoint and not documents.

Comment: @KubaghettothefreshTestobun I'm still not sure to understand your exact goal. Do you want to listen to any update that occurs to any hello document OR you want to loop over ALL the hello documents in one operation?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec , the first one. I need to listen to any update in any "hello" document and do this permanently. 

When people will use my app, there will be more and more of this "hello"-documents available and they will be created at random times a day and I want to keep track of them with this function since the beginning of their existence.

Comment: @KubaguetteTheTestobun Ok, so your current approach (current trigger type) is the correct one. See my answer for the solution of your deployment problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem comes from the fact that you use **twice** the **same wildcard identifier**, i.e. `chatID`, when defining your Cloud Function.

Changing the code to use two different identifiers, as follows

```
exports.createpushnotification = functions.firestore.document('chatrooms/{chatDocID}/{chatSubcollectionID}/hello').onUpdate(..);
```

should do the trick.

---

In addition, since the fetch operation is asynchronous, and since your Cloud function is a background Cloud Function, you need to return the promise returned by `fetch()` in order to indicate to the Cloud Function platform that it can terminate the function. See the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) for more details.

Do as follows:

```
return fetch("https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send", {..})
```

Comment: This helped me with deploying the function, now I do not receive any error anymore! However, it seems like the function doesnt do what I really want. 

I do not receive any notification on my phone whatsoever when I change my "hello" file. 
It weird because the frontend code, inside my app I mean, must be working because when I use https://expo.dev/notifications it works and displays a notification on my phone. Is my function messed up?

Comment: Because I can send the notification through the website, Im pretty sure my app itself is not the problem, it must be something with the cloud function that is not working for me here. Maybe Im wrong, Im not sure.

Comment: I'm afraid we cannot help you anymore with the amount of information you are currently sharing. You'll need to debug your code by adding a `catch()` block and also see if you have errors on the Expo's Push API side.

Comment: No worries, its working. I made the silly mistake to save the "partner1pushkey" inside my firestore document with the semicolons at start and end even though it is already declared as string, removed them and now its perfect. Thank you for your help!